# Local host WAMP server is not working?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wampserver

HEllo,

I have download the wordpress at my local machine. and designing my website using wordpress. i have download the wanp server and it working fine at loca server last 2 months.

2 days back i run the registry cleaner software for maintenance purpose. but after that when i tries to open wordpress logine details at local server (my machine) it not openeing.

WAMP server shows YEllow partly and white.

Kindly suggest me wt do i do so it will start working again.

Thanks,
Rahul.

Comment: Did you try testing port 80 to see if anything else might be using it? There should be a menu item for it in the system tray icon, under Apache settings.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you have Skype running before starting Wamp server it doesn't start, probably as it's using the same port.

Comment: Had the same problem some time ago and this was my solution also. +1